# ORA-06576: Not a valid function or procedure name

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, oracle11g, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to call a Stored function in Oracle, im sure that it exists and that I have access to it, I can call it from SQL Developer, but when I try to call it from Java Springboot using jdbcTemplate, it says that it isn't a valid function or procedure.

Im using the same user in SQLDeveloper and in Java connection who is also the package owner.

The specific error is:

```
oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-06576: Not a valid function or procedure name.
```

Im calling it this way:

```
User inspector = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("CALL PKG_USUARIO.INICIAR_INSPECTOR(1, '123456')", newUserMapper());
```

I searched this problem but didnt solve it in this case, appreciate the help!, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Check that:

1. You are connecting to the correct database server.
2. You are connecting to the correct database instance on the server.
3. You are connecting as the correct user.
4. You have the correct name for the procedure. (And that the procedure has not been given a non-standard name that would require double quotes around the identifier such as `PKG_USUARIO."inicar_inspector"`.)
5. The user you are connecting as has permissions to execute the procedure.
6. That the procedure has compiled successfully.
7. That the procedure is actually a procedure and not a function, which would need to have a return value and be [called using](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28765/addfunc.htm#TDPJD211):

   ```
   {? = CALL PKG_USUARIO.INICIAR_INSPECTOR(?,?)}
   ```

   or

   ```
   BEGIN ? := PKG_USUARIO.INICIAR_INSPECTOR(?,?); END;
   ```

Comment: I tried the "PKG_USUARIO."inicar_inspector"" but its still not working.

Maybe it needs the variable to storage the result, but I though that its the RowMapper for... I'll look how to add that variable then. Thank you.